# Coroutine channel is not emitting data from inside firebase authentication callback

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I'm building an app with firebase phone authentication.

And I'm using a repository which emits events through a coroutine channel, so that when the OTP code is sent, an `OtpSent()` event is sent through the channel.

The issue is, when the OTP code is sent, the view model which consumes that channel, doesn't get the update.

Worth to mention that the OTP sending process includes an intent to a CAPTCHA website (works automatically through firebase authentication library), and the OTP event is being emitted to the channel right after that.

**`BaseRepositoryImpl.kt`**:

```
abstract class BaseRepositoryImpl() : BaseRepository {
    private val _errorChannel = Channel<RepoError>(CONFLATED)
    private val _eventChannel = Channel<RepoEvent>(CONFLATED)

    override val errorChannel get() = _errorChannel
    override val eventChannel get() = _eventChannel


    override suspend fun emitError(repoError: RepoError) {
        _errorChannel.send(repoError)
    }

    override suspend fun emitEvent(repoEvent: RepoEvent) {
        _eventChannel.send(repoEvent)
    }
}
```

**`AuthRepositoryImpl.kt`**:

```
class AuthRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    ...
) : BaseRepositoryImpl(), AuthRepository {
    ...
    override suspend fun sendOtp(
            phoneNumber: String,
            activity: Activity,
            resend: Boolean
        ) {
            withContext<Any?>(ioDispatcher) {
                val builder = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .setActivity(activity)
                    .setTimeout(2L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setCallbacks(object : 
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credentials: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                            ....
                        }

                        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                            ...
                        }

                        override fun onCodeSent(
                            verificationId: String,
                            forceResendingToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
                        ) {
                            super.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken)
                            ...
                            // this line emits the event (its being called)
                            ioScope.launch { emitEvent(OtpSent()) }
                        }
                    })
                if (resend) {
                    builder.setForceResendingToken(_resendToken!!)
                }
                PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(builder.build())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`OtpViewState.kt`**:

```
@HiltViewModel
class OtpViewState @Inject constructor(
    ...
) : BaseViewState() {
    ...
    override fun attach(){
        ...
        viewModelScope.launch {
            eventChannel.consumeEach {
                // this consumer isnt getting triggered
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code reaches the `emitEvent(OtpSent())` line, but the consumer isn't getting the event.

Thank you all for the help :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see why it behaves like this at a first glance. However, if you want to try using Kotlin coroutines and Firebase authentication with Google, most like this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo thats a great anc close architecture but mine is different, im emitting through a channel